# Como Distribuir RIA com JNLP e Java 8

Tags: java, segurança, java-8

Desenvolvi uma aplicação e na hora de distribuir com o JNLP, encontrei um impasse. Com o Java 8, ele pede para assinar os JARs e o certificado deve ser de um CA reconhecida.

Eu assinei os JARs com um certificado gerado por mim (só funciona para o localhost).

Alguém sabe como fazer para que eu possa fazer com os JARs auto-assinados?

Comment: Qual é o seu sistema operacional?

Answer (score 4):

Isto não é uma resposta completa, mas vou usar como exemplo o JAR do [tIDE](http://tide.olympe.in/) com o qual eu tive este problema há alguns dias atrás. Trata-se de um JAR executável por JNLP que também é auto-assinado e foi bloqueado no Java 8.

Estou usando o Windows.

Primeiro, abra o Painel de Controle e procure o ícone do Java:

[image: Painel de Controle]

Clique no ícone do Java e uma nova tela se abrirá. Estando lá, vá na aba "Security" (ou "Segurança") e acrescente o seu site ou URL à lista de exceções:

[image: Painel de Controle Java]

<sup><sup>[fonte](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/win_controlpanel.xml)</sup></sup>

No Mac, você pode encontrar algo parecido com o que está acima, indo no *System Preferences*. <sup><sup>([fonte](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_controlpanel.xml))</sup></sup>

No Linux, você pode adicionar os sites de exceção ao arquivo `${user.home}/.java/deployment/security/exception.sites`, sendo um site/URL de exceção por linha. <sup><sup>([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25950032/540552))</sup></sup>

Comment: Eu ja fiz algo parecido, esta url qual é?
É a que coloco no CodeBase no manifest ou a da aplicação onde esta o jar?

Comment: @ljzf Da aplicação de onde está o JAR, de onde ele é baixado.

Comment: eu coloquei o "http: //10.0.0.10:8080/myapp/" será que faz diferença alguma?

Comment: @ljzf Eu acho que apenas `http://10.0.0.10` já deve ser o bastante. De qualquer forma, isso deve ser fácil de testar para você.

Comment: ok, estou achando que é a porta 8080 que esta a me dar trabalho, não consigo remover ela no glassfish a partir do arquivo domain.xml

Comment: fiz o teste e nada

Comment: @ljzf Se você adicionar um host específico no seu arquivo de `hosts` do seu sistema operacional e utilizá-lo como exceção, será que funciona? No linux você o encontra em `/etc/hosts`. No windows você o encontra em `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Os hosts lá definidos têm prioridade sobre o DNS. Além disso, vale você criar uma página HTML local acessível por este seu host e a partir dela baixar o JNLP.

Comment: Criei uma aplicação simples e testes ela funcionou mas com o javafx nao esta funicionando